# How to set an index in the name of the file from a Registry Value using CreateFile?

Tags: winapi

I would like to create a .txt file on any directory, let's say: C:\Demo.txt but I would like to add an index retrieved by a **Registry Value** using the `CreateFile` function (I think that's the function I have to use for that).

For example, if the DWORD **DemoValue** has a content of "**2**", the file would be: **Demo(2).txt**

Can I do that with `CreateFile` and `RegQueryValueEx`?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to do it "automatically" - you would have to retrieve the registry value using `RegQueryValueEx`, build the filename using a formatted string function like `StringCchPrintf` and then create the file.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it "automatically" - you would have to retrieve the registry value using `RegQueryValueEx()`, build the filename using a formatted string function like `StringCchPrintf()` and then create the file.

Comment: Can I use that function in a Win32 Windows App?

Comment: Yes these are Win32 functions.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanPotter. I thought CreateFile had any property to set that, but I am going to try doing it this way.